# How to test views using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, unit-testing, view

We work with a database that isn't ours to manage. We defined some views on it so that our code (C# with Entity Framework) can simply map to these views. These views will be given to the database owners later on. They will implement them so that we can use them.

During testing, we mock that database. We used Entity Framework Tools on a backup of the database, to generate a DbContext of it. We create it each time when running tests. Is this even the way to go?

During testing we would like to insert data in some tables, and read the results out of the related views. We do this to test the views as well as the C# code that will act upon it (there is non trivial logic in those views).

What is your opinion on this? Shouldn't we recreate the mock-database each time but use a static one with the views already defined? Should we define the views in C# so that they are created on the database? Is our approach completely wrong? How do others tackel similar problems?

Comment: I'd love to know if you ever found a way to do this as I am in a similar situation at the moment and I'm struggling to see how best to test entities based on views. We can test inserting data to underlying tables OK but I'm not sure what the best practice is for then testing that we can retrieve that data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

### **"During testing, we mock that database...."**

In EF version 6 or later you can also mock DBContext.

### **"During testing we would like to insert..."**

Do you have the source code of the inherited DBContext? My recommendation to handle the views just like tables. Create a class for it(Entity) and in your applicationDBContext just map the View like a normal table.

```
 public DbSet<ImAView> ImAViews { get; set; }
```

With database migration you can modifiy your view with normal T-SQL Script.

### **"What is your opinion on this? Shouldn't"**

If you are testing the application (also data access layer in version 6) you can mock everything. Do not use database creation this will make your test very slow and is some cases the tests will be depends on other tests.

IF you want to test the database it self or migration or some bulk opeations then you have to create a database (you can do everything in SQL Server without C#) and feed it with data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We already mock the database using DbContext. And we already defined the views as if they were tables. So we have a DbContext class with DbSets for each table and view.

What we want to achieve is that those views (which we use as if they are tables) actually "work". If I have a view X which will be based on tables A, B and C; I want to insert data into tables A, B and C and continue working with view X.

Comment: You are in the correct way but the problem the maintenace for the views is hight and complex think about migration think about entities modifiction etc.

Comment: I don't get why I would need migrations. The database we will be testing isn't our database. We are not even able to modify it. We have a local read-only backup which we used to generate a DbContext. It is this DbContext for which we will generate a database for each test so that we can populate it and test on it. It is also on this mocked DbContext database that we want to test these views. These views will not be deployed to production as such. These views will have to be created manually by the owners of the database, after we tested them.

Comment: So you want to do a Structural Testing in Relational Databases. to evaluate the whole story I need to see the code! Views often implement interesting business logic. Things to look out for include: Does the filtering/select logic work properly? Do you get back the right number of rows? Are you returning the right columns? Are the columns, and rows, in the right order?

Comment: Bassam, I appreciate your comments but they are not related at all and thus not very helpful. First of all I can't just show you my repository of a couple of gigabytes or chunks of it and expect you to understand it right away. Furthermore, it is company code so I'm not blatantly uploading it on the internet. Next; my views are working, that is not the problem either. My only issue is "How to mock an EF context while defining views so that they these are usable in tests." I have a not so elegant solution right now, hence my question...

Comment: Gurdt I dont need to see your company code and I do not want  to review code of a giga bytes you can simplify the problem in 2 or 3 classes(very simple prototype) and few lines because I can not see the problem you can mock the view exactly as you doing with the table mock the DbSet's. @Slauma maybe you can help us? http://stackoverflow.com/users/270591/slauma